# How to set Time delay to after calling function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that randomly changes the background of a page in react. But I want the background color to FADE to the next random color so I tried below.

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  quotes: [],
  selectedQuoteIndex: null,
  background: 'green'
}

changeBackground() {
let background = "#" + ((1<<24)*Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
this.setState({background});
}, 2000;

assignNewQuoteIndex() {
this.setState({ selectedQuoteIndex: this.generateNewQuoteIndex() });
 }

backgroundQuoteChange(){
this.assignNewQuoteIndex();
this.changeBackground();
}

render() {
return (
  <div style={{
    width: '100vw',
    height: '100vh',
    backgroundColor: this.state.background
  }}>

<Button id="new-quote" 
 size={'small'} 
 onClick={backgroundQuoteChange}>Next Color & Quote
</Button>
 )
```

I use this function on a button which has onClick. Not working :/

Comment: Can you please share the code also where you are passing for the `onClick` prop in the component? Also how you are initiating the state in the component?

Comment: I've update the code but it is a lot bigger than that. There is nothing wrong with the syntax (except for the changeBackground function which needs to have the delay)

Answer (score 0):

Just set a transition on the respective div with 1s delay and ease-in-out timing function.

```
transition: background-color ease-in-out 1s;
```

Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-franklin-d6z99

I'd highly suggest getting your basics of HTML, CSS and JS stronger before jumping into a framework. You definitely need some work there.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use css transtion

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quotes: [],
      selectedQuoteIndex: null,
      background: "green"
    };
  }

  changeBackground = () => {
    let background = "#" + (((1 << 24) * Math.random()) | 0).toString(16);
    this.setState({ background });
  };

  render() {
    return (
     <>
       <div
         style={{
           width: "100vw",
           height: "100vh",
           transition: "background-color 1s",
           backgroundColor: this.state.background
         }}
       />

       <button type="button" onClick={this.changeBackground}>
         Next Color & quote
       </button>
     </>
   );
  }
}
```

Here is a [the example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3geex1?file=src/App.js)